# Keras : training with an array as an input

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I am quite new to machine learning, and I recently began to learn how to implement basic neural networks on Python using the library Keras.

I started with an elementary example (training a network so it can predict the value y = f(x) = x).

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=1, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
data = np.array([x for x in range(0,1000)])

for i in range(0, 1000):
   model.fit([np.array([data[i]]), np.array([data[i]]), nb_epoch=1, batch_size=1, verbose=0)
```

I would like now to apply a similar algorithm to train a network so from a list of integers L, it would return a list of three values of my function f (basically : [f(L,0), f(L,1), f(L,2)]). So the input this time is an array of 5 integers, and the desired returned output is a list of 3 floats.

However, I do not manage to code properly the fit method in the for loop, I get an error message: "Expected to see 1 arrays but instead got the following list of 2 arrays: ...". I tried to play around with some arguments of the Dense constructor (input_dim, input_shape, input_size) but I still do not seem to be able to make it work...

So basically, does anyone know how to implement correctly a network that takes an array as an input and returns an array of a different length?

Thank you very much for the help and support,

-- smgr

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Please learn neural networks first in order to use Keras. If you have two input dimensions, you data should be of the form `(batch_size,2)`. You don't need to iterate over `fit`. You can use `nb_epoch` argument. The question and your motive is extremely unclear to me. So I cannot effectively answer this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am going to try to be more precise...
I intent to do some Q learning using neural networks. Hence, the input of my network is a state s (described by an array of 5 integers) and the results is an array of the values Q(s,a) where a can take three values (0,1, or 2).
The thing is, I do not manage to compile my model with an array as an input (compared to the code I showed that works, where the network uses only one integer as an input), the code returns an error regarding its size apparently.

Comment: What I can do is point you [here](https://github.com/farizrahman4u/qlearning4k).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your final output has 3 dimensions your last **Dense** layer has to have 3 columns.

You do so with

```
model.add(Dense(3))
```

If your input has 5 dimensions your first Dense Matrix will have 5 lines.

That's done with **input_dim** parameter in your **first** Dense layer.

```
model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=2, activation='relu'))
```

You can see now that this first dense layer matrix is a 2 lines by 10 columns matrix. Since the next matrix will necessarily have 10 lines (so that dimensions will match), in the next layer you have only to define the number of columns. Hence you pass a single dimension argument to every following layer.

Since it's a regression problem, using 'mse' as loss should work (as you correctly selected).

Your dataset in this situation should be two matrices:

- an input matrix with the input samples (one column for each attribute, so 5 columns). N by 5 matrix
- an output matrix with the output samples (one column for each attribute, so 3 columns). N by 3 matrix

In both situations you should have the number of lines to be the same: the total number of samples N.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation! My code has still some minor bugs to be fixed but this part is now fully operational, many thanks.